# Conflict over require() function between Facebook SDK (xd_arbiter.php) and RequireJS

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, requirejs

### Setup / Background

We're trying to [load the Facebook SDK through RequireJS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/requirejs/):

```
require.config({
  'shim': {
    'facebook' : {
      'exports': 'FB'
    }
  },
  'paths': {
    'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/vb'
  }
});
```

(`/en_US/all/vb.js` is basically identical to the usual `/en_US/all.js`, but also includes FB's experimental [Music Bridge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/bridge/) feature.  However, the problem still exists with either version of the SDK.)

... and the main body of the SDK is loading correctly.  However, during initialisation of the Facebook SDK it creates an iframe which makes a request out to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&domain=<DEVELOPMENT_SERVER>&origin=1&redirect_uri=<...>
```

... which then redirects to:

```
http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=27#
```

... which in turn returns a minimal HTML document with a script tag that defines a number of additional javascript modules for the Facebook SDK.

### The problem

Both the main Facebook SDK *vb.js* and the *xd_arbiter.php* script seem to make use of a `require()` function (defined in each file in their default top-level scope) to load Facebook SDK modules.

While the main Facebook SDK (*vb.js*) is loaded through a RequireJS shim (and hence - I believe - its scope is limited by RequireJS, so the `require()` function it defines doesn't interfere with RequireJS's global `require()` function), because the *xd_arbiter.php* code is loaded in an iframe it's somehow being executed in the **global** scope of the browser.

This seems to be causing a conflict with the RequireJS version of the function - every time the page loads we get a RequireJS error in *xd_arbiter.php* (line 13):

```
Error: Invalid require call
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs
```

... which seems to be caused by the *xd_arbiter.php* code calling what it thinks is its own `require()` function, but is actually the RequireJS version of the function... and hence the parameters passed to the function are invalid for RequireJS.

We're currently in the middle of trying to replace an old legacy/custom/hand-rolled module system with a nice, common, relatively-standard library like RequireJS, and this has brought us to a screeching halt.

### The question

Can anyone suggest a way to either:

- Persuade *xd_arbiter.php* to define a `require()` function *not* in the global scope,
- In addition to *vb.js*, also load the scripts defined in *xd_arbiter.php* through RequireJS instead of via an iframe, or
- Persuade RequireJS to not define a global `require()` function (for legacy reasons we're actually using a thin wrapper around RequireJS's `require()` function so our existing module code keeps working for now, so it's no great imposition to change the name of the method we call to define RequireJS modules, as it's only used in one place in the code)

... without doing something gross like hacking/forking RequireJS or the Facebook SDK?

Alternatively, have we missed something really obvious somewhere that we should be doing differently?  I'm pretty new to both RequireJS and the Facebook SDK, so I'm fully aware we may have just overlooked something/made a stupid mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - it turned out to be a bug in the function we were (for legacy, compatibility reasons) using to wrap calls to RequireJS's `require()` function, that was legitimately calling `require()` with incorrect parameters.

For some reason some quirk of our setup was causing Firefox to report any and all JS errors on the page as having occurred in xd_arbiter.php (on a line which - by sheer dumb fluke - happened to have a call to the FB SDK's own require function!), instead of whichever actual file the error occurred in.